# Restore changed menu state after rotation of a device

Tags: android, menuitem, screen-rotation

I'm writing an application, which has a menu with buttons and an image. I press the button and label of the button changes from "Record track" to "Stop recording". The issue is when I rotate my device, the activity with buttons gets killed by the OS. So, I understood that I have to save my data before it's get killed in `onSaveInstanceState` method and then restore it in my `onCreate` method. Something like this:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(final Bundle saveInstanceState) {
    saveInstanceState.putSerializable("image", image);
    saveInstanceState.putSerializable("buttonState", isRecording);

}
```

And:

```
if (savedInstanceState != null) {                                
    isRecording = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("buttonState");  

    if (menu != null) {                                          
        MenuItem recordButton = menu.getItem(R.id.track);

        if (!isRecording) {
            recordButton.setTitle(R.string.rec_track_label);     
        } else {
            recordButton.setTitle(R.string.stop_rec_track_label);
        }
    }                                                            

    Image = (Image)savedInstanceState.getSerializable("image");

}
```

And while it perfectly restores my image, I still have issues with the menu: for some reason it always stays "null", so it will never change label of my button despite that it should be recreated every time, when Activity starts and I save it in a private object of my Activity:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    new MenuInflater(this).inflate(R.menu.actions, menu);
    this.menu = menu;
    return (super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu));
}
```

Any ideas what am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Just curious: your `if (isRecording)` statement seems to be reversed; why are you setting the `stop_rec_track_label` text if it's not recording?

Comment: @eightx2 You're correct, it was a mistake :-/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should move your `menu != null` block into [onPrepareOptionsMenu](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPrepareOptionsMenu%28android.view.Menu%29):

```
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    MenuItem recordButton = menu.findItem(R.id.track);

    if (isRecording) {
        recordButton.setTitle(R.string.rec_track_label);     
    } else {
        recordButton.setTitle(R.string.stop_rec_track_label);
    }
}
```

As this method is called directly before the menu is being shown to the user.

Comment: You should use ``menu.findItem(R.id.track);`` and not ``menu.getItem(R.id.track);``.